# Vuex does not provide an export named 'createStore'

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I try using vuex with Vue3 and Vite. After installing it with yarn like `yarn add vuex@next --save`

I get the error:

`The requested module '/vite-dev/@fs/home/app/node_modules/.vite/vuex.js?v=f336efac' does not provide an export named 'createStore'`

Any idea how to solve this?

EDIT:

store.js

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
...

  const store = createStore({
    plugins: [createPersistedState()],
    state() {
      return {...},
```

main.js - just importing store file

`import { store } from "./store.js";`

Comment: @fix The version is 4.0.2

Comment: Works fine in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vuex-vite-typescript-starter?file=src/store.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it solved by deleting `node_modules` and re-installing the dependencies. Not sure why that solved it tho.

Comment: try using `npm ci` next time

Comment: @flx What's the difference in that case?

Comment: `clean install` it removes node_modules and reinstall all modules

Comment: Also don't forget to restart `vite` (`yarn dev`) afterwards or you'll see no change